# How to show sharepoint context menu on my javascript page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have created a page and created list with the help of REST APIs, and also done some styling. This all working fine, but I need to show the custom sharepoint list context menu on this as below image. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I guess question require some more clarification. Where do you want to include this context menu?

Comment: I will explain step by step, what I have done. 
1. Created a custom list. 
2. Created a page
3. Added a script editor and inserted my HTML into this . Along with HTML I have REST API calls to get the data from list that was created before.
Rest of all are working fine. But in the customized list in the page (each row) I need to show the context menu. Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at the Fabric UI Callout https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/callout

Comment: @Bunzab has provided excellent link. here is what you want https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/contextualmenu